# How to Insert a JSON code with PHP & SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I am trying to Insert my Categories SQL tables with a JSON in the below format.

```
    [
        {"id":21, "children": [{"id":4},{"id":7}]},
        {"id":6},
        {"id":5},
        {"id":20},
        {"id":10},
        {"id":9}
    ]
```

I have tried to make it possible with this Code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['category'])){
        if(in_array($_GET['key'], $_SESSION['key'])){
                    unset($_SESSION['key'][array_search($_GET['key'], $_SESSION['key'])]);
            $i = 1;
            $rootof = array();
            foreach($_POST['category'] as $cat => $parent){
                if($parent == 'children'){ 
                    $p = "NULL";
                    $root = "NULL";
                }else{
                    $p = intval($parent);
                    if(isset($rootof[$p])){
                        $root = $rootof[$p];
                        $rootof[intval($cat)] = $rootof[$p];
                    }else{
                        $root = $p;
                        $rootof[intval($cat)] = $p;
                    }
                }
                mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE ads_categories SET category_order = $i, category_parent = $p, category_root = $root WHERE category_id = ".intval($cat));
                $i++;
            }
            echo 'Success';
        }else{
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
```

I expect Saving the Categories by Id and subcategories (children) to Database.

I want to Insert Id 21, 6, 5 to categories->id,
if array has Children it means that it has subcategories.

subcategories has category_parent id to main category

Example: Categorie ID 4 category_parent would be 21

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show, with an example, what rows you want inserted into your `ads_categories` table based on the data in your JSON example.

Comment: @o-jones Added :)

Comment: Do you need indefinite recursion? or will there be a maximum relationship of parent-children (no grandchildren)?

Comment: maximum relationship of parent-children